# Laravel helpers render view display empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have this global helper for displaying error page

**app/Helpers/ErrorPage.php**

```
function error_page($txt,$url=false,$button_txt='Go back'){
    if( !$url ){
        $url = url('/');
    }
    $data = [
        'page' => 'error page',
        'text' => $txt,
        'button_url' => $url,
        'button_text' => $button_txt
    ];

    return view('utility.error',$data);
}
```

then add it to autoload

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/ErrorPage.php"
    ]
},
```

then did `composer dump-autoload`

then in my controller, call

```
error_page('This account is already verified!');
```

and it display empty unless if I `do echo view('utility.error',$data);` from the `error_page` function, the view renders the page with unacceptable abnormalities on the layout.

any help, ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your error_page function just returns a view. It doesn't return it to the controller or stop the request processing. Where is the code where you call `error_page()`?

Comment: @bassxzero in my controller

Comment: @bassxzero did test it via route display, same result

Comment: You need to return the view from your controller. `return error_page('This account is already verified!'); `

Comment: ah yes, its woking now. can you post your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

The controller expects you to return a view, string, etc. for it to send back as a response.

You are creating the view in your error_page() function, but you aren't using it.

This is how it should be used in your controller.

`return error_page('This account is already verified!');`